# Change value input AngularJS with a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to change the value of a input when the value doesn't satisfy a condition. In this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/peWTfa1SIc1CICpp3I1g?p=preview), when I add a Detail and change the unit price input if the value isn't a number should change the value to "0.00".

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if ( isNaN(newValue) ) {
    scope.item.price = "0.00";
    console.log("isn't numeric");
  } else {
    console.log("is numeric");
  }
});
```

The problem is that the value isn't a number prints "isn't numeric", but also prints "is numeric". This happens only when I change the value of "scope.item.price".

Is there any way I could change the value of input without being called twice scope.$watch ?

Comment: I think that the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) would be the way to go. It is the standard for when you are dealing with the ng-model data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a deep $scope.watch on `invoice.items` as such:

```
  $scope.$watch('invoice.items', function(){
    $scope.subtotal=0;
    angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items,
    function(item) {
      $scope.subtotal += item.qty * item.price;
    });

    $scope.igv= $scope.subtotal * 0.18;

    $scope.total=$scope.subtotal  + $scope.igv;

  }, true);
```

See the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/5rzjeIG0C76a8l0ZAp4u?p=preview , notice the `true`at the end for the deep watch.

Comment: It's best to avoid deep watching for performance. The ngModel he wants to format already has a watch registered, so I really recommend using it.